I can't use the blogger api it gives me a 403 error even though i am authorized
This is my code that is supposed to get an access token using a service account I have set up (which is done correctly) then use the access token to authorized an API request to the blogger API (which isn't done correctly for some reason) to make a blogger post:
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
creds.refresh(request)
access_token = creds.token

print(access_token)

print("access token granted")

headers = {
'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
'Accept': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.post(
f'https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/6084243137377471911/posts?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D&key=%7Bblogger_api_key%7D',
headers=headers,
json=data,
)
print(response.text)

gives a super long access token along with the access token granted thing + this:
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource.",
"errors": \[
{
"message": "We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden"
}
\]
}
}

I just copied most of it and I expected a 200 OK response with the json data of the post but all I got is that 403 error
